# Send a user input with axios GET to the backend to query Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I'm working on an app that sends a Get request to Firestore from the node.js backend.

Something like this:

```
app.get("/documents", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  let userData= [];

  db.collectionGroup("User")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        userData.push(doc.data());
      });
      res.send(userData);
    });
});
```

I would like to get a user input from the frontend, send it to the backend using axios and have it work as a query field like so:

Frontend:

```
mounted() {
    axios
      .get('/url-here/', {
    params: {
        value1: user_input
    }
  },
```

Backend:

```
db.collectionGroup("User")
        .get()
        .where("UID", "==", user input here )
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you've to access to them via the request param (called `req` in your signature). You're doing a get so the params would be query string:

```js
db.collectionGroup("User")
        .get()
        .where("UID", "==", req.query.value1)
```

read more: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query